# How do I print text onto the game screen

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have this if statement where all the code works perfectly and the pause function works and all, but... After the game has paused I want to print some text on the screen to the user, but it only prints in the console, could you please let me know how to print the text on the game device screen, Thank You!

```
if score[0] == 10 {
    pauseGame()
    print("HEY")
    sleep(5)
    let skView = self.view!
    skView.presentScene(scene)

}
else if
    score [1] == 10 {
    pauseGame()
    print("HEY")
    sleep(5)
    let skView = self.view!
    skView.presentScene(scene)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't print text to the view(game screen) using something like a print statement, simply because iOS has a graphical user interface which requires you to specify things like where to put the text on the screen, what size/font/color and so on. That said it is relatively easy to put text on the screen, you can do this my making a textLabel of some sort.
Here is how you do this with an UILabel, put this code inside the **if** statement:

```
let textLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 100, height: 20)) //You can change the postitioning obviously, keep in mind (x: 0,y: 0) is actually the top left corner
textLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
//textLabel.font = UIFont(name: "ChalkboardSE-Bold", size: 10) //If you want a custom font
textLabel.textColor = UIColor.green
textLabel.textAlignment = .center
self.view.addSubview(textLabel)
```

*For a list of possible fonts see [this webpage](http://iosfonts.com/), and replace the "ChalkboardSE-Bold" with the name of the font you want.*

Comment: Do you know why I get the error... Type 'SKView' has no member 'addChild'

Comment: Oops my mistake. Don't put this code inside the if statement but rather inside the scene itself. Also change the skView.addChild(textLabel) to addChild(textLabel). I have also updated my answer

Comment: In the line SKView.addChild

Comment: So how do I call it to run when the score has reached 10?

Comment: Have you actually use the scene you are presenting when a score of 10 has been reached?

Comment: No, that's what I'm asking, how do I show that text after the score has reached ten?

Comment: No but what I mean a normal Swift game uses a SKScene which actually handles all those things. Because you load in a scene in the skView.presentScene(scene) line, I thought you used that for your game. If you actually want to do game related things(like score checking) inside of the ViewController, I can change my answer if you would like?

Comment: Yes please if you wouldn't mind, I'm not using a different game scene